# Passing variables between JS and CSHTML

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I'm building a dropdown menu on an admin panel that changes the time zone of the displayed time. I have a TimeHelper C# script written that has a function that converts the time given a string that has the time zone. It returns a type DateTime.

I'm running into confusion as to how to properly implement the conversation between the JS and C#, here's what I have written:

```html
<script>
  function get_option()
  {
    var time_zone = document.getElementbyId("time_set");
    if (time_zone == "Server")
      time_zone = "UTC";
    if (time_zone == "Device")
      time_zone = @Model.timeZoneId;
    var time_to_disp = @WebApp.Utils.TimeHelper.GetDateTimeByZone(time_zone);
    document.getElementById("time_on_page") = "Current time (" + time_zone + "): " + time_to_disp;
  }
</script>
```

Mostly, it's about time_zone in the @WebApp... line. Visual Studio says that time_zone doesn't exist in the current context, which I understand but don't know how to fix.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _server-side_ code and _client-side_ code.  You can't do that.

Comment: So, how do I pass client-side information over to the server? POST?

Comment: AJAX is easiest IMO.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good candidate to communicate with the server about.  Why not just rewrite your C# function in JS?

Comment: How you're passing the value timeZoneId from the controller, could you include the controller code in your question? - Tip: Use JQuery instead of javascript, the code gets way better than that.